# What methodology is used by Tortoise-SVN to indicate a changes in sub-tree (sub-directories)?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, timestamp

I Implement a version-contol system on a CAE software (called '**Engineering Base**', for whom interested), and i was wondering how Tortoise SVN know what subtrees have uncommited changes.

Tortoise-SVN, has a way of knowing exactly what sub-directory has changes pending in.
and it indicates using the Overlay Icon.

I wonder if anyone Looked inside the Source and figured out How they do that?

How they use the file TimeStamps/File System Monitor/Other methods inorder to achive that?

---

My Question in Summary:
What methodology is used by Tortoise-SVN to indicate a changes in sub-tree (sub-directories)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I Found the exact method used at the SVN-BOOK at Subversion.Org

made it all clear,

if anyone want to know as well, this is where to look
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/

Answer (score 1):

SVN, like most version control systems, keeps a mirror copy of all of the source files in a hidden `.svn` directory. It detects changes by simply checking if the current file's contents is different from the one in the `.svn` directory. I don't know how Tortoise-SVN decides when to invoke this algorithm (it's rather fast, so the svn command line tool does not bother caching the results). Using timestamps would make sense, but I notice it getting out of date often, so I suspect it just checks whenever a folder is refreshed or on whatever hook explorer offers it.